# SQLALCHEMY Sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-32795: cannot insert into a generated always identity column

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

I have created the following Oracle tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "OHM"."TRANSACTION_MASTER" (
    "TRANS_TYPE" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    "INVOICE_NO" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "INVOICE_DATE" DATE, 
    "VENDOR" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "VENDOR_ADDRESS" VARCHAR2(250 BYTE), 
    "TRANS_CATEGORY" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "TRANS_AMOUNT" NUMBER, 
    "TRANS_DESC" VARCHAR2(250 BYTE), 
    "PAYMENT_MODE" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "PAYMENT_DESC" VARCHAR2(250 BYTE), 
    "TRANS_NO" NUMBER  GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (
        START WITH 1000000000 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCYCLE
    ), 
    "TRANS_AMOUNT_WORDS" VARCHAR2(500 BYTE), 
    "VENDOR_EMAIL" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    CONSTRAINT "TRANSACTION_MASTER_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("TRANS_NO")`
```

and

```sql
CREATE TABLE "OHM"."TRANSACTION_DETAILS" (
    "TRANS_NO" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ITEM_CODE" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ITEM_NAME" VARCHAR2(250 BYTE), 
    "ITEM_CATEGOTY" VARCHAR2(250 BYTE), 
    "ITEM_UNIT_PRICE" NUMBER, 
    "ITEM_QUANTITY" NUMBER, 
    "ITEM_QUANTITY_MEASURE" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "ITEM_NET_AMOUNT" NUMBER, 
    "ITEM_DISCOUNT_VALUE" NUMBER, 
    "ITEM_TOTAL_AMOUNT" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
        CONSTRAINT "TRANSACTION_DETAILS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("TRANS_NO", "ITEM_CODE")
    USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
    TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE, 
        CONSTRAINT "TRANSACTION_DETAILS_FK1" FOREIGN KEY ("TRANS_NO")
        REFERENCES "OHM"."TRANSACTION_MASTER" ("TRANS_NO") ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE
    )
```

I have the following Python code:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, Date,Float,ForeignKey,Identity
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from base import Base

class TRANSACTION_MASTER(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'TRANSACTION_MASTER'
    trans_no =Column( Integer,Identity(start=1000000000, cycle=True),primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)
    trans_type = Column(String(1))
    invoice_no = Column(String(20))
    invoice_date =Column(Date) 
    vendor = Column(String(100))
    vendor_address = Column(String(250))
    trans_category = Column(String(20))
    trans_amount =Column(Float)
    trans_desc = Column(String(250))
    payment_mode = Column(String(20))
    payment_desc = Column(String(250))
    items = relationship('TRANSACTION_DETAILS', back_populates = "trans")
    def __init__(self, trans_no,trans_type,invoice_no,invoice_date,vendor,vendor_address,trans_category,trans_amount,trans_desc,payment_mode,payment_desc): #CHANGE THIS
        self.trans_no=trans_no
        self.trans_type=trans_type
        self.invoice_no=invoice_no
        self.invoice_date=invoice_date
        self.vendor=vendor
        self.vendor_address=vendor_address
        self.trans_category=trans_category
        self.trans_amount=trans_amount
        self.trans_desc=trans_desc
        self.payment_mode=payment_mode
        self.payment_desc=payment_desc

class TRANSACTION_DETAILS(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'TRANSACTION_DETAILS'
    trans_no =Column( Integer,ForeignKey('TRANSACTION_MASTER.trans_no'),primary_key=True )
    item_code = Column(String(20),primary_key=True)
    item_name  = Column(String(250))
    item_categoty  = Column(String(250))
    item_unit_price =Column(Float)
    item_quantity =Column(Float)
    item_quantity_measure  = Column(String(20))
    item_net_amount =Column(Float)
    item_discount_value =Column(Float)
    item_total_amount  = Column(String(20))
    trans = relationship('TRANSACTION_MASTER', back_populates = "items")
    def __init__(self,trans_no,item_code,item_name,item_categoty,item_unit_price,item_quantity,item_quantity_measure,item_net_amount,item_discount_value,item_total_amount):
            self.trans_no=trans_no
            self.item_code=item_code
            self.item_name=item_name
            self.item_categoty=item_categoty
            self.item_unit_price=item_unit_price
            self.item_quantity=item_quantity
            self.item_quantity_measure=item_quantity_measure
            self.item_net_amount=item_net_amount
            self.item_discount_value=item_discount_value
            self.item_total_amount=item_total_amount
```

I am trying to insert data into the `transaction_master` table via the following code:

```py
from datetime import date
from base import Session, engine, Base
from Transaction_Master import TRANSACTION_MASTER
from Transaction_Master import TRANSACTION_DETAILS    
    
session = Session()
    
Tm = TRANSACTION_MASTER('','C','ENTHE','10-JAN-2022','MANJUSHA','ADDRES','GROCERY',123.00,'DESC','CC','BII')
        
# 9 - persists data
session.add(Tm)
        
# 10 - commit and close session
session.commit()
session.close()
```

It throws error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-32795: cannot insert into a generated always identity column
[SQL: INSERT INTO "TRANSACTION_MASTER" (trans_no, trans_type, invoice_no, invoice_date, vendor, vendor_address, trans_category, trans_amount, trans_desc, payment_mode, payment_desc) VALUES (:trans_no, :trans_type, :invoice_no, :invoice_date, :vendor, :vendor_address, :trans_category, :trans_amount, :trans_desc, :payment_mode, :payment_desc)]
[parameters: {'trans_no': '', 'trans_type': 'C', 'invoice_no': 'ENTHE', 'invoice_date': '10-JAN-2022', 'vendor': 'MANJUSHA', 'vendor_address': 'ADDRES', 'trans_category': 'GROCERY', 'trans_amount': 123.0, 'trans_desc': 'DESC', 'payment_mode': 'CC', 'payment_desc': 'BII'}]
```

Please help me on this error. I know I don't need to pass this `trans_no` field for identity column insert. The add function considers all the fields by default. How can I bypass this? Should I be defining this relationship between the tables for query and update purpose? How can I resolve the issue with the insert?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Python, but - nonetheless - let me try.

As you already concluded yourself, you shouldn't try to provide value for an identity column whose value is always generated automatically.

What's even worse, you're using the same `TRANS_NO` as a foreign key column in `TRANSACTION_DETAILS` table. It means that you have to know its value before inserting the detail row. If the *master* `TRANS_NO` is generated automatically, you'd have to return its value (into a local variable - speaking from Oracle's point of view) so that you could then use it (the local variable) in `insert into transaction_details` statement.

Oracle offers the `returning` clause (see an example e.g. [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dml-returning-into-clause)), but I don't know whether there's something similar in Python. If not, then consider **not** to use the identity column, but provide the primary key (and, subsequently foreign key) value yourself. How? Create a **sequence** (in Oracle) and fetch its value - it is the `sequence.nextval` you'd use.

Comment: Yeah, This is true. I asked this question for Python  SQLALCHEMY ORM. Is there anyway to  bypass this field in SQLALCHEMY ORM? or how to add data to tables having columns GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY.

Comment: I was able to achieve this by just removing the trans_no from the init function. Thank you

Comment: I was able to achieve this by just removing the trans_no from the init function. it will insert a record by generating an ID, How can I get this ID back , so That I can insert records for the transaction details?

Comment: See accepted answer, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35327135/retrieving-identity-of-most-recent-insert-in-oracle-db-12c

Comment: @Littlefoot yes Python cx_Oracle and python-oracledb support RETURNING INTO binds, see https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#dml-returning-bind-variables